# Open a page available only on the server (backend proxy)

Tags: php, javascript

I have a frontend application that need to call a reporting services, opening a new window with a javascript function like this :

```
window.open('http://somedomain.com:8080/report')
```

What I wanna do now is, since the tomcat server is on the same machine of the backend application(and on the same machine of the web server - php), avoid to open the 8080 port on the internet.

In simple words, I need a way to connect the tomcat application server(through localhost) and proxy the connection to the frontend without requiring to open the port 8080 of the server to the all world. Is it possible ?

How can it be done ?

To generate html page on the server I use php...

**EDIT/UPDATE**

The page on the tomcat application server is not static, it has a loading mechanism and need user interaction ...

Comment: does the java program require tomcat? Could you running it from the command line with a exec call from php?

Comment: No, it requires to be run inside tomcat, and it is available at the http://localhost:8080/report address ...

Comment: Google is good guy. Always has [something](http://snipplr.com/view/45552/proxyjsp/) :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use PHP's [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) functions to get the information you need via PHP (using `localhost:8080`) and use this as a PHP proxy. Then use Ajax to retrieve the information from the PHP proxy.

Comment: The problem is that the page on the tomcat application server is not static and need interaction ...

Comment: It's possible to send get/post parameters with cURL. Your proxy could easily pass through any parameters required.